# Angular 7 virtual scroll: how to attach to parent div scrollbar?

Tags: angular, scroll, virtual, parent, angular7

I have two   `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport> some code</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`  in   `<div class=parent_div>`  .
how can I attach parent div scroll  to childs `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>some code </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`??

Comment: what do you mean by "attach div control to children"?

Comment: I want scroll parent div, and attach it to children's  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>.